# How to append by pdfwriter in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, itext

I wish to append text to a file by PDFWriter without replacing each text.

If using streamwriter I can only add `True` behind but what about PDFWriter?

```
StreamWriter Code:
System.IO.StreamWriter( FILE_NAME, True)

My Current PDFWriter Code:
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\New folder\" + Reader.GetString(10) + Reader.GetString(9) + ".pdf", FileMode.Append))

pdfDoc.Open()

pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(String.Format("{0}|{1}", Reader.GetString(9), Reader.GetString(17)))) 

pdfDoc.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`PdfWriter` is a class for generating PDFs from scratch (yes, one can import contents from other documents but fundamentally it is for new content).

If you want to add new content (using iText high level API layout mechanisms) to an existing document, you should create the new content in a separate document (which you may hold in memory only by means of a `MemoryStream`), create `PdfReader` instances for the existing document and your new, intermediary one, and then combine them using `PdfCopy`.

If you want to add new content (using iText less high level APIs) to an existing document, you can use a `PdfStamper`.

---

As an aside, concerning:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\New folder\" + Reader.GetString(10) + Reader.GetString(9) + ".pdf", FileMode.Append))
```

Using `FileMode.Append` is a bad idea, PDF is not a format in which you can simply concatenate files to get a merged result.

Comment: `While Reader.Read()
Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\it.administrator\source\repos\WindowsApp6\WindowsApp6\New folder\" + Reader.GetString(10) + Reader.GetString(9) + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
pdfDoc.Open()
pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(String.Format("{0}|{1}", Reader.GetString(9), Reader.GetString(17))))
pdfDoc.Close()
End While`

This code will always take the first line of data from my database. I wish to get all lines data under the same PDF. Trying with your suggestions but still stuck on it.

Comment: You want all data to go into the same PDF, on the other hand the file name of the PDF depends on the dataset. This combination does not make sense.

Comment: But currently system will only write the 1st data related to the customer code into the pdf instead of all related data.

Comment: Expected result will be: PDF file will be rename base on customer code and customer name. Then all data that related to that customer code will write into the same pdf.

Comment: //This Part Will Rename My PDF based on Customer code & name//  


Dim pdfDoc As New Document() Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\it.administrator\source\repos\WindowsAp‌​p6\WindowsApp6\New folder\" + Reader.GetString(10) + Reader.GetString(9) + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))  


//This Part Will Filled In The Data Related To That Cust Code//    


pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(String.Format("{0}|{1}", Reader.GetString(9), Reader.GetString(17)))) pdfDoc.Close()

Comment: Previously write using streamwriter its work fine, but after use the pdfwriter the result become different

Comment: *"PDF file will be rename base on customer code and customer name. Then all data that related to that customer code will write into the same pdf."* - The you had better order the database query result by *customer code and customer name*, so all data for the same file comes in one block. *"Previously write using streamwriter its work fine"* - You can trivially append to regular text files or CSV files. Obviously that does not work for most binary files, in particular not for PDFs.